# How do I use CouchDB's reduce() function?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I'm trying to aggregate some data I have in CouchDB. There are photo documents in the database and rating documents in the database. Each rating document looks like so (sans _id and _rev):

```
{
   "type": "rating",
   "rating": 3 // Integer values are identifiers that map to a string; e.g 1 might mean 'funny'
   "photo": "as9i83ufsafa09uj" // The id of the photo that this rating points to.
}
```

What I want to do is a get a count of each rating type for each photo.

```
{
   "key": "as9i83ufsafa09uj", "value": [1, 7, 8, 6] // 1 '0' rating, 7 '1' ratings, etc.
   "key": "photoid2", "value": [3, 0, 0, 8]
}
```

I'm using CouchDB views' MapReduce to achieve this aggregation.

```
"map": "function(doc) {
   if(doc.type == 'rating')
   {
      emit(doc.photo, doc.rating);
   }
}",

"reduce": "function(keys, values, rereduce) {
   var result = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0);

   values.forEach( function(key, value)
   {
      result[value]+=1;
   });

   return result;
}"
```

The map returns:

```
{"total_rows":55,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"0aa2c4c9a031eedbcf2795cabc1679be","key":"4aa5ec26-26b8-490a-a9cc-620a0d2136b9","value":0},
{"id":"29f363432e008f5934b4160292e18680","key":"4aa5ec26-26b8-490a-a9cc-620a0d2136b9","value":3},
{"id":"646d0d764623bc2f3ed1354ac03b583e","key":"4aa5ec26-26b8-490a-a9cc-620a0d2136b9","value":2},
...
{"id":"fa5be78402171e3bf1eb1cf91c5fda6e","key":"c63b78b6-ad92-426c-ab64-c9a6ae229b31","value":1}
]}
```

The reduce returns witb group_level=0:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":[1,1,1,1]}
]}
```

with group_level=1:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"4aa5ec26-26b8-490a-a9cc-620a0d2136b9","value":[2,2,2,0]},
{"key":"5ad3de4b-d25b-42d3-95e0-df7661becbf3","value":[2,2,2,2]},
{"key":"7600710b-9ae3-4312-876c-ad352722dac3","value":[2,2,2,2]},
{"key":"959f48a2-5018-4938-aab4-086d8824dd75","value":[2,0,0,0]},
{"key":"c63b78b6-ad92-426c-ab64-c9a6ae229b31","value":[2,2,2,2]}
]}
```

I'm familiar with MongoDB's map reduce and this function would work using their schema. What do I need to tweak for this to work in CouchDB?

**UPDATE**
This is the final reduce function that worked for me. I wasn't addressing the rereduce parameter correctly. Thanks goes to Marcin Skórzewski for helping me to better understand rereduce.

```
"reduce": "function(key, values, rereduce) {

        var result = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if(rereduce == true)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            {
                var value = values[i];

                for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++)
                {
                    result[j] += value[j];
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            value = values[i];
            result[value]+=1;
        }

        return result;

        }"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not using `rereduce` properly. The `values` element and returned data is not the same type. In case of only one group level and small size of data (to fit in the single B-tree node) it could work fine, because no rereduce has to be run. Take a look at the [reduce doc](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_Functions) and the meaning of `rereduce` argument for `reduce()`.

In case `reduce()` is run for values emitted from `map()` they are integers, but if you reduce values obtained by prior `reduce()` they are arrays. You can make use of the `rereduce` and in case it is `true` add arrays. Or you can emit arrays in map (e.g. to get `[0,0,0,1]` instead of `3`) and always add arrays in `reduce()` without worrying about `rereduce` argument.